# Is there a way find files in linux modified in particular time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, datetime, find

Which best way in linux show only the files modified (not created) after a specific date, hour...?

Need list files, that where modified from date 2016-08-10 00:00:01 till 2016-09-01 09:36:00

Tried several ways with `find . -type f -mtime`, but it is not suitable for my requirement time interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your version of `find` supports the [--newerXY](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Comparing-Timestamps.html) option, try this one:

```
find . -newermt "2010810 00:01" \! -newermt "20160901 09:36:00"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.